# Load or Read a JSON from local in Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am looking to read a json file, namely `config.json` from a AppScript to generate a Google Form from the meta data in the `config.json`. I am not sure how to read the JSON file - could someone help me with it please? Some example code would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're like me, you may have looked here to see how to store the JSON file **inside the actual Apps Script project** (e.g. alongside Code.gs) and then retrieve it in Code.gs.

I did this:

- Add an HTML file to your project.
- Remove *all* the content of the HTML file and put in your JSON
- In your Code.gs file, use something like the following:

```
//Assume the file you added to your project is called 'my-json.html'

const jsonString = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("my-json.html").getContent();
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: does it actually matter what the extension is? will this fail if your file does not have ".html" extension? I'd rather not have to rename my file

Comment: @Somo S. The method I'm describing involves adding a file to the Apps Script "Files" list, where Code.gs is, and pasting your json file's contents into it (so you're not even using your original file at this point). And the only way to add a file here is to click the + icon and select either "Script" or "HTML". "Script" will add a .gs file, so that won't work. Only other option is "HTML", which gives you an .html. file, and you can't even change that extension.

Comment: okay that makes sense, thank you for your timely response

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It is funny that App Script does not let you store actual json files, but this is a great work around.

Comment: Can we pass multiple object data? For example for the record key, there is a 10 array. and for the names key, there is 20 array of object.

Comment: @YadavShiv For this method, you can put **any valid JSON text** into the "HTML" file and it will work. This includes an array of objects, or even an object whose keys are equal to an array of objects. If you want to use separate JSON files, then you can repeat the steps in the answer but with multiple "HTML" files. Hopefully these points answers your question.

Comment: okay thanks for replaying. it has solved the problem

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that your file is in Google Drive, you can use the DriveApp service to read the file and parse it.

```
function getFileContent() {
  var fileName = "config.json.txt";
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    Logger.log(json);
  }
}
```

Make sure that Google Drive has not converted the text file into a native format else the script won't be able to parse it.