# JSON File on Drive to Google sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a few **JSON** files on my **Google Drive** from which I need to extract data into a spreadsheet. I have tried the **ImportJson** function from **github** but that is to fetch the JSON file directly from the API but the JSON files I have on my drive are not accessible to me directly from the API.

Can anyone help me in how can I get the JSON stored on the drive to be imported in the Google sheets.

The sample JSON is attached herewith:

```js
{
  "gstin": "12ABCDE",
  "fp": "082019",
  "b2b": [{
        "ctin": "2312ABCDEY",
        "cfs": "Y",
        "cfs3b": "Y",
        "inv": [{
          "val": 1072,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "samt": 81.76,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 908.48,
              "camt": 81.76
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "02-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "642",
          "chksum": "7a58ec7342001040acf4509176ba22ceb03d9ad0ecf7e74d572af0ec4d8429fa"
        }, {
          "val": 1072,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "samt": 81.76,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 908.48,
              "camt": 81.76
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "17-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "722",
          "chksum": "0597afa614e27aa78dc252f2530172007e574f52d1ceea9e433e04f474414bbf"
        }],
        "fldtr1": "10-Sep-19",
        "flprdr1": "Aug-19"
      }, {
        "ctin": "22AAB1Z5",
        "cfs": "Y",
        "cfs3b": "Y",
        "inv": [{
          "val": 459463,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1801,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 389375,
              "iamt": 70087.5
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "30-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "2495",
          "chksum": "15ef392cfd4fd3af2fce1ad8549f93bac20cf17308df9bf9256ae838db45a440"
        }],
        "fldtr1": "11-Sep-19",
        "flprdr1": "Aug-19"
      }, {
        "ctin": "23AFEZI",
        "cfs": "Y",
        "cfs3b": "Y",
        "inv": [{
          "val": 9350,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "samt": 713.16,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 7924,
              "camt": 713.16
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "02-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "00075",
          "chksum": "cb4fe40cb2f39f8782a160ece273991daae68b739dfba454ffeb364150d03580"
        }, {
          "val": 12312,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "samt": 939.07,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 10434.09,
              "camt": 939.07
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "10-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "00084",
          "chksum": "1d0fa36c2a7f1ffe7d7c07a829056e4e28fd0300fd593f91ba8216ace4e54f2a"
        }],
        "fldtr1": "05-Sep-19",
        "flprdr1": "Aug-19"
      }, {
        "ctin": "23ECVPSQ",
        "cfs": "Y",
        "cfs3b": "Y",
        "inv": [{
          "val": 10200,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "samt": 777.97,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 8644.1,
              "camt": 777.97
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "13-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "650",
          "chksum": "43bcf7c73bf94013344111d95c6f80dea47980ef4bfd3093a33e2c385baa2fdd"
        }, {
          "val": 4745,
          "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
              "csamt": 0,
              "samt": 361.91,
              "rt": 18,
              "txval": 4021.18,
              "camt": 361.91
            }
          }],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "23",
          "idt": "30-08-2019",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "727",
          "chksum": "fae1037d879dc718f322e8622a5323344a6cf88b68f68620aaa7ed5d92a15a23"
        }]
      }
```

Data sample to look like this

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve JSON specific content from Google Drive with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325466/how-to-retrieve-json-specific-content-from-google-drive-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks for the help but this does not solve my problem as the suggested code does not retrieve data to my sheet.

Comment: How do you want the data in the JSON to be formatted on the spreadsheet side? A screenshot, showing how nested fields would be written (how would they be located in the different columns), could be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to retrieve all the nested properties in your object (after you've converted the JSON string using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and write the corresponding key-value pairs to the first two rows of your spreadsheet (key in row 1, value in row 2). When the value is an object, the `key` will be written in row 1, but row 2 will remain blank (e.g. `b2b`).

In this case, you could use recursion to iterate through and retrieve all the nested properties and values from the object. The function could be something like this:

```
function allProps(element, array, parent = "") {
  if (typeof element === 'object' && element !== null) {
    if (parent != "") array.push([parent, ""]);
    const entries = Object.entries(element);    
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      const nextParent = Array.isArray(element) ? "" : entry[0];              
      allProps(entry[1], array, nextParent);
    });
  } else {
    array.push([parent, element]);
  }
}
```

The idea is that, for each value, it checks if the value is an object or a primitive data type. If it's the former, `allProps` gets called recursively, and if it's the latter, the key-value pair is added to the spreadsheet.

And you could call it this way:

```
function JSON_to_Spreadsheet() {
  const id = "JSON_FILE_ID"; // Change to your FILE_ID
  const json = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Get JSON text from Drive file
  const obj = JSON.parse(json); // JSON text to JS object 
  let array = []; // 2D array where the output will be stored
  allProps(obj, array, parent = ""); // Call function recursively
  array = array[0].map((_, colIndex) => array.map(row => row[colIndex])); // Transpose 2D array
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet(); // Retrieve active sheet. Change if you want to access another sheet or another spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(1,1,array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array); // Write 2D array to your sheet.
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

#### Edit:

If you want each `ctin` header (apart from the first one, in column D) to occupy a new row, you can do the following once you have retrieved the 2D array:

- Retrieve an array with all the indexes from `array[0]` where the header is `ctin` (excluding the first one).
- Using these indexes, add each `ctin` segment to the main array.
- Write the array to the sheet, taking into account that the different rows have different lengths. If you wanted to use a single `setValues` (that would be recommended for efficiency purposes), you'd first have to find the maximum length of the inner array elements, and make all the inner arrays have this length.

The function `JSON_to_Spreadsheet` could be something like this:

```
function JSON_to_Spreadsheet() {
  const id = "JSON_FILE_ID"; // Change to your FILE_ID
  const json = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Get JSON text from Drive file
  const obj = JSON.parse(json); // JSON text to JS object 
  let array = []; // 2D array where the output will be stored
  allProps(obj, array, parent = ""); // Call function recursively
  array = array[0].map((_, colIndex) => array.map(row => row[colIndex])); // Transpose 2D array
  const ctinFirstIndex = 3; // Column D (first ctin)
  const ctinIndexes = array[0].reduce((acc, current, i) => {
    if (current === "ctin" && i !== ctinFirstIndex) {
      acc.push(i);
    } 
    return acc;
  }, []); // Find indexes for all ctin headers
  for (let i = 0; i < ctinIndexes.length; i++) {
    [0,1].forEach(rowIndex => {
      const sliced = array[rowIndex].slice(ctinIndexes[i], ctinIndexes[i + 1]); // Extract ctin segment
      sliced.unshift("","",""); // Columns A to C should be empty
      array.push(sliced); // Add each ctin segment to the 2D array
    });    
  }
  [0,1].forEach(rowIndex => array[rowIndex].splice(ctinIndexes[0])); // Remove other ctin data from first two rows
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Copy of Data");
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 2, array[i].length).setValues(array.slice(i, i + 2));
  } // Write array to sheet. Rows have different dimensions, so cannot be written all at once
}
```

In this case, the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lamblichus this finally worked. Just a little piece of more help needed from you. The data is now arrange side by side ranging from column A to BBJ. can we get the relevant data in the tabular form with headers rows same as extracted in the first row. Row change for each 'ctin' as each 'ctin' can contain may 'inv' rows

Comment: @Harsh I'm glad it helped. I'm not sure I understand `get the relevant data in the tabular form with headers rows same as extracted in the first row`. Could you rephrase this? Also, I think this is not what you asked for in the original question, so I'd consider posting another question for this.

Comment: I have created a sample table from the imported data from your script which was in only 2 rows I have kept the headers of each data for your reference so that you can understand where I am stuck. Thanks a ton for all your time and help. [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pKFaYE9d9hgIwiKilIAOFTA7XJhKMGnAivnyB1MMWYc/edit?usp=sharing) @lamblichus

Comment: @Harsh I have updated my answer with your new issue. I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks you @lamblichus you have certainly solved my problem completely. Thanks a TON to you for giving time and energy for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for a specific json file. Since opening a JSON file in drive is a bit hard to get the file ID you can use the first function to get the ID.

**EDIT:**

When you run the first function you can look-up the jsonfile ID in the logs -> View -> Log. Then insert this ID in the second function under // Change file id

```
//With this function you can get the ID of you json file. After running see the view -> Logs for the info.
function getDriveFileID() {

  //Change id of the drive folder found in the url
  const folderID = "1UN3xxxpE8mXjHHJJF";
  const driveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  const driveFiles = driveFolder.getFiles();

  while(driveFiles.hasNext()){
    let file = driveFiles.next();
    console.log(file.getName()," = ",file.getId());
  };
}

function JSON_from_DRIVE() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //change output sheetname
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  //Change file id
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById("1IPyU2nxxxxx_lr0F").getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const dataAll = JSON.parse(file);
  const dataRows = dataAll['b2b'];
  
  const rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]);
  const rows = [rowHeaders];
  for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    var rowData = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowHeaders.length; j++) {
      rowData.push(dataRows[i][rowHeaders[j]]); 
    }
    rows.push(rowData);
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); 

}
```

**EDIT: this should work custom for your json file.**

```
//With this function you can get the ID of you json file. After running see the view -> Logs for the info.
function getDriveFileID() {

    //Change id of the drive folder found in the url
    const folderID = "1UN3xxxpE8mXjHHJJF";
    const driveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    const driveFiles = driveFolder.getFiles();

    while (driveFiles.hasNext()) {
        let file = driveFiles.next();
        console.log(file.getName(), " = ", file.getId());
    };
}

function JSON_from_DRIVE() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //change output sheetname
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
    //Change file id
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById("1IPyU2nxxxxx_lr0F").getBlob().getDataAsString();
    const dataAll = JSON.parse(file);
    const b2b = dataAll['b2b'];
    const dataRows = [];

    b2b.forEach(base => {
        base.inv.forEach(inv => {
            const obj = {
                "ctin": base.ctin,
                "cfs": base.cfs,
                "cfs3b": base.cfs3b,
                "val": inv.val,
                "num": inv.itms[0].itm_det.csamt,
                "csamt": inv.itms[0].itm_det.csamt,
                "samt": inv.itms[0].itm_det.samt,
                "rt": inv.itms[0].itm_det.rt,
                "txval": inv.itms[0].itm_det.txval,
                "camt": inv.itms[0].itm_det.camt,
                "inv_type": inv.inv_typ,
                "pos": inv.pos,
                "idt": inv.idt,
                "rchrg": inv.rchrg,
                "inum": inv.inum,
                "chksum": inv.chksum,
                "fldtr1": base.fldtr1,
                "flprdr1": base.flprdr1
            }
            newObj.push(obj);
        });
    });

    const rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]);
    const rows = [rowHeaders];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
        var rowData = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < rowHeaders.length; j++) {
            rowData.push(dataRows[i][rowHeaders[j]]);
        }
        rows.push(rowData);
    }

    sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply to my problem. I have executed the above script but getting the following error " Cannot convert undefined or null to object " for line  const rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]); Please help

Comment: Did you first run the first function and see in the Log the file id? And pasted this id in the second function

Comment: yes sure did that. If I remove the [0] from the line than only 4 values are fetched from the JSON to the Sheet and rowHeaders.length value is set to 4 when I logged it.

Comment: Can you update the post with your json file (just the structure, you can alter the values) to get a cense of your json. I tested it with this: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: I updated the script above, added: const dataRows = dataAll['b2b']; as you can see in you sample, b2b is a array of objects, you have some nested objects as well. So this would not work like charm. You have to manipulate the incoming json to get what you want. Plus.. what is it what you want? There ar multimple "val" inside a "ctin"

Comment: RemcoE33 have tried your new script, the const newObj was not defined hence i defined the same as const newObj = []; after that the same error was given again for line const rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]); as "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object (line 151, file "Code")" Please help